# MySQL Select Where First Character Is

Tags: mysql, select

How do I select the first character of a cell and use that to define what is returned?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at MySQL "String" and "Control Flow" [Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions.html).

For example:

```
SELECT IF( LEFT( myField, 1) = 'a', 1, 0) FROM myTable;
```

will return 1 for the fields that start with 'a' and 0 for all other values

Comment: select * from table where LEFT(category,1)!=6 is another example, when you want to restrict the table, to items on a category like 1.1 , 1.2, 5.0, but hide 6.X category.