# How to get row in sql by only a 1 char of one of the fields

Tags: mysql

I have field `strcont Varchar (40)` in MySQL database and `char c`. So I need all rows where `strcont` starts with `c`

For example:

```
Table - tbl. Columns - id, strcont, sthOther.
strcont = {"abcd", "adcs", "bdcs", "bjfh"}
```

and `c = 'a'`. 
So it returns only `"abcd"` and `"adcs"`

Comment: `...WHERE strcont LIKE 'a%' `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Where First Character Is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213916/mysql-select-where-first-character-is)